# Disable a specific windows' notification - windows 10

Tags: notification-area

My default keyboard is in italian. Today I've set up greek's keyboard (downloaded by control panel of windows 10). The problem is the following notification:

[image]
[image][image]

Translation: greek, optical character recognition, setup failer. This notification occurs many time (16/05/2017, 17/05/2017 and so on) for this reason I'd like to disable it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please translate your screenshots into English.  How you diable notifications for a specific application is well documented.  What part of that process, exactly, are you stuck on though?

Comment: Load image in an image editor, put english translation into screenshot, so you are not limited to 0.1% of the Superuser population that understand Italian.  *In any event, the notification is due to a UWP application you have running, which doesn't support Greek.*  So you need to determin which application that is, then disable notifcations, for that application.

Comment: Is your question really how to hide the error message or how to fix the issue?

Comment: Hi @Dave, I'd like to disable=hide it forever (but only the above error message).

Comment: Rather than hiding this error you should investigate why it is occurring and resolve the issue. That is how you will get the error to go away.